# Set Access Permissions for a Whole Group on a Directory

Tags: c#, windows, security, io, filesystems

I am writing a C# application which needs to create a folder, and then give DOMAIN\Users full permissions. When I try to pass in `Environment.UserDomainName + @"\Users"` it throws a `System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException`. Currently, I have this code:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectorySecurity dirSec = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();

// All users should have full control.
dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserDomainName + @"\Users", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

dirInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSec);
```

How can I make this "work", as in allowing users full control of the directory which is stored in `path`?

This is the full exception:

[image: Exception]

Comment: code looks fine.  For whatever reason, it can't find the username.  I used your code on my machine and it worked 100% as expected.  Maybe double check to see that your domain\users group exists? Maybe the machine you're testing on isn't joined to the domain?

Comment: @DavidGreilach Yes, it certainly exists: http://i.imgur.com/7Wb84VE.png. - Also I checked what `Environment.UserDomainName + @"\Users"` returns and that's all as expected.

Comment: Currently, I am just testing it on my local machine, but I plan to use it on a network once development on my home computer has finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some testing on my pc and found that when adding a domain user this worked:

```
Environment.UserDomainName + @"\Users"
```

For a local machine account, I had to do:

```
@".\Users"
```

Since you're testing on your home PC I'm assuming that you aren't on a domain and are trying to add the local machine Users group.

Comment: So I would need to do two different versions depending on the type of system (network or local)?

Comment: If so I guess it would work in a try and catch statement.

Comment: you could do a try catch or just test if its domain first then do local if it isnt

Comment: You might instead take advantage of the fact that the local Users group typically contains the domain Users group.  This is the usual approach: just add the local Users group, and if the machine is in a domain, the domain Users group will automatically have the same access.

Comment: That's a really solid suggestion.  I think I've only run into 1 place that wasn't like that.

Answer (score 1):

Group name could also be entered from outside as below ;

```
public static void SetGroupUsersPermission(string Path,string groupname)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path);

    DirectorySecurity dirSec = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();

     dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserDomainName + @"\" +
     groupname, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

     dirInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSec);
}
```

Comment: ***groupName*** in `Active Directory` ?